# Adding numbering ahead of code for fscanf output

Tags: c, file-io

This is the code I use to scan in a text document, what I need to do is add numbering *i.e.* 1. for line 1 etc.

I've tried different methods like using a for loop but it doesn't work since its scanning one `char` at a time.

Is there a more effective way to scan the entire text in from a file and add something like numbering to it?

Thanks in advance.

```
char line[80];
line[0] = '\0';

FILE* file = 0;

file = fopen("sample.txt", "r");

int current = fgetc(file);


for (int k = 0; k < 35; k++)
{   
    while (EOF != current)
    {
        printf("%c", current);
        current = fgetc(file);
    }
}
fclose(file);
```

Comment: What does the image have to do with the problem? Also, if you just want to number lines, read one line at a time with `fgets()`.

Comment: please don't post images of code or of input/output text.

Comment: [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I hadn't explained it clearly and was using an image to help explain better.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

```
int i = 0;
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file)){ //reads until the end of the file
    printf("%d. %s", ++i, line); // prints the line with its number
}
```

Note that the string will be stored in `line` and will be overwritten at every cycle, if you want to store those for later use you'll need an array of strings and concatenate the number with the line using [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/?kw=snprintf):

<kbd>**[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BDsFX6eQ4NFPBOVX)**</kbd>

```
char line[80];

FILE *file = fopen("sample.txt", "r");

if(file == NULL){
    perror("fopen");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int i = 0;
char lines[36][85];

while (i < 35 && fgets(line, sizeof line, file)){ // reads until the end of the file or 35 lines are read
    snprintf(lines[i], sizeof lines[0], "%d. %s", i, line); // concatenates line number with the line and stores it in lines array
    printf("%s", lines[i]);               // prints the line with its number
    i++;
}
lines[i][0] = '\0'; //empty sentinel line, usefull as stop condition
fclose(file);
```

**Off-topic**: You should verify the return of `fopen` to make sure the file is actually opened.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the code I use to scan in a text document, what I need to do is add numbering i.e. 1. for line 1 etc

Sure, so just output the numbers after a newline.

```
// we start with a newline
bool was_newline = true;
unsigned line_number = 1;
for (;;) {
    const int c = fgetc(file);
    if (c == EOF) { break; }
    if (was_newline) {
        // there was a newline? We output line number
        was_newline = false;
        printf("%d ", line_number);
        line_number += 1;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {
        // och, we read a newline
        // we will need to output line number the next time
        was_newline = true;
    }
    printf("%c", c);
}
fclose(file);
```

[Tested on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5aKnr4).

Answer (score 0):

after:

```
file = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
```

insert:

```
int lineNum = 1;

printf( "\n%3d ", lineNum );
```

after:

```
    printf("%c", current);
```

insert:

```
    if( current == '\n' )
    {
        lineNum++;
        printf( "%3d ", lineNum );
    }
```

However, suggest using: `fgets()` as that will input a whole line from a text file in one function call. Note: need to allocate space for a whole line of characters.  perhaps changing `current` to `char current[1024];`